# Play Framework - Display custom error on CSRF token mismatch

Tags: playframework

I have the following controllers on Play 2.4:

```
    @AddCSRFToken
    public static Result form() {
        return ok(form.render());
    }

    @RequireCSRFCheck
    public static Result doForm() {
        return ok();
    }
```

If `@RequireCSRFCheck` fails, how do I catch the error in `doForm()` so I can display my own error messages?

Comment: Haven't tested this, but you may be able to intercept the error in a Custom HttpErrorHandler (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Supplying-a-custom-error-handler) instead of handling it in the doForm method.